# hg grep not checking removed files

Tags: mercurial

I've been trying to follow [this guide](http://jcbsnd.com/2014/05/find-and-remove-large-files-in-a-mercurial-repository) to remove large files from the history of my repository. The problem is that I can't get this `hg grep` command to work:

`hg grep -l ".*" "set:size('>10MB')"`

Specifically, it fails to print any file which does not exist in the current working directory. If at any point in the past I `hg rm`'d a file, it is not listed by this command. If I update to a changeset before a given file is removed, then it *does* correctly list that file. I've been poring over the documentation for `hg grep` but I can't understand why it would ignore files that were removed from the repository at some point. Checking files that are no longer in the working directory seems to be the entire purpose of `hg grep`.

Is there any way that I can get `hg grep` to detect removed files, or in general to get a list of all files over a given file size that were ever committed to the repository, even if they have since been removed?

Comment: Are you using the `--all` option? Not sure if that matters.

Comment: @Edward I thought it might, but with `hg grep --all -l ".*" "set:size('>10MB')"` I still only see files that exist in the current working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While iondune's solution works, it will probably take a very long time on reasonably large repos. A quicker solution would be to look at hg's metadata directly. From the project working directory:

```
$ find ./.hg/store/data -type f -exec du -ah {} + | sort -hr | head -n 20
```

This will give the list of the 20 files with the largest diffs. The mapping between actual files in the repository and how they are stored as Mercurial metadata is [pretty straightforward](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/behind-the-scenes.html).

Answer (score 0):

I eventually gave up on trying to do this with an `hg` command and simply used this bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

EndRevision=568  # Latest Revision
Repository="/path/to/repository"

mkdir -p "Results"

for i in $(seq 0 "$EndRevision") ; do
    echo " --- Doing revision $i of $EndRevision ---"
    hg up -C -R "$Repository" -r "$i"
    find $Repository/* -type f -exec du -ah {} + > "Results/From${i}"
done
```

along with the following one-liner:

```
cat Results/From* | sort -hr | uniq | head -n 25
```

It worked well enough for my needs (identifying a comprehensive list of large files in the repository history).

Answer (score 0):

`hg locate -r "set...` may be easier. Something like

`hg locate "set:size('>10MB')" -r ":"`

Comment: I just tested: `hg locate` has the same issue than `hg grep`, it won't show files that have been removed as of the current tip.